# Uppercase first letter in UIWebView (iOS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to uppercase the first letter in UIWebView?  UIWebview doesn't have an autocapitalizationType property on it, like UITextField and UITextView (ex: `textfield.autocapitalizationType = .sentences`)

I tried in my HTML file:

```
<div id="editor-container" autocapitalize="on" style="padding:0px;margin-top:0px;font-family:'GothamPro-Light';font-size: 15px;"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with iOS or a web view. This seems more like an HTML question. And please clarify. Is this for an input field in an HTML form?

Comment: Sorry, just making sure, because there is an autocapitalize="sentences". You don’t want that, you only want the first letter capitalized?

Answer (score 0):

Please give this a try. It uses JavaScript to switch `autocapitalize` between `words` and `none`. I needed to blur() and focus() the div on each `input` event, otherwise the keyboard wouldn’t pick up the change in the `autocapitalize` setting.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getEditor() {
    return document.getElementById("editor")
}

function tickle(editor) {
    // This gets the keyboard to pick up the change in the autocapitalize setting.
    // Save the selection.
    selection = document.getSelection()
    anchorNode = selection.anchorNode
    anchorOffset = selection.anchorOffset
    editor.blur()
    editor.focus()
    // Restore the selection.
    document.getSelection().setBaseAndExtent(anchorNode, anchorOffset, anchorNode, anchorOffset)
}

function textChanged() {
    editor = getEditor()
    text = editor.textContent
    if (text.length != 0) {
        editor.autocapitalize = "none"
        tickle(editor)
    } else {
        editor.autocapitalize = "sentences"
        tickle(editor)
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="getEditor().addEventListener('input', textChanged)"><div id="editor" contentEditable="true" autocapitalize="sentences"></div></body>
</html>
```